# Add another Contract Model to WorkFlow Service

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have two work flow that be hosted through WorkflowServiceHost and those contain some Receive activity that expose services to out.

some services that my workflowservices must expose is general, for example suppose there is a monitorring service that return Tracking Information about one wf instance.

Solution 1 : in any workflow definition there is a receive activity that return Tracking Information.

but i look for another solution without defining this functionality as activity.
notice that i dont want use another service to expose these functionality, i want expose these functionality in same work flow service
Tanks

(sorry for bad english writing)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose everything as one service you have 2 options:

1. Add the tracking requests to the workflow service as you suggest
2. Create a wrapper service, a regular WCF .svc file, and forward the requests to the workflow as needed and handle the tracking outside of the workflow.

If you really want to expose just a single external service I would go for the second option. That said, I normally just expose 2 services as they are different things and services are for machine consumption and not human consumption so the 2 URL's are no problem.